# Create column filters in excel document using apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI for creating excel sheets. i have a requirement where i need to create columns with sorting(drop down) functionality as shown in screenshot1. on click of dropdown we should display dropdown as shown in screenshot2. please help me how to achieve this functionality. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by creating an excel template with already predefined sorting drop down, and open that file and populate with data and should work.

Comment: Hi Zemzela thanks for your reply. i am not getting please can u share the snippet or atleast which methods needs to be called? Thanks!

Comment: what do you not getting? I'm sorry but have no example. Show me your code I will tell you what are you doing wrong

Comment: Hi Zemzela, how to create columns in excel?